# Android not totaly use swap memory - MemTotal is not increase when I adding swap

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, swap

I have add a lot of swapmemory and disable the buid-in zram, on my Android phone.
It is ok, htop and swap info show the entire swap. I have put a script to do it at startup, and it work well.
The original zram memory have 400Mo and now the swap use only 200Mo or 300Mo.

I show that HighTotal and LowTotal (we can see it with : cat /proc/meminfo) not take the swap memory it stay the same between adding swap.
Both of them just equal at MemTotal and MemTotal is just the total of physical memory.

I don't have HighTotal and LowTotal on Ubuntu, is it a parameter in java configuration ?
I don't see Which parameter have to be modify to take the swap memory as usable memory.
Anyone see a solution for me ?

Thanks in advance
David

I try application with kernel tune, including application to make swap, it is not work better. I try to look on kernel config, I don't find anything. I search on java parameter but I don't find anything.